# Is there any quality loss when using a place command in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector-graphics, resizing

I am using “Place” command in Photoshop to import `.ai` file. Is there any quality loss after using this steps:

- Save file in Illustrator at some default size—i.e 400x400px—using `.ai` extension or any other vector image format,
- Import file in Photoshop using “Place” command.
- Resize file to 800x800px.
- Confirm the “Place” command.

Or it would be better approach to create an art of size 800x800 directly in Adobe Illustrator, and then place it in Photoshop without resizing?

I know that quality suffer when resizing bitmap, but is this happen before we apply “Place” command as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the Illustrator file is a vector image, then quality should not change since vector images are basically a pile of instructions to draw an image and the “default” size you save it as in Illustrator is just a default size to be used when no other size is specified. Such as when you just open it straight with no intervention in Illustrator or Photoshop..

Comment: This make some sense...I got different answers on different forums...One of them was : "You have to make image 800x800 or larger, and then shrink it down"... Which I find kind of confusing, because if I have to do that, then what is the purpose of Place command, vectors and initial shrinking option when using Place command...Thanks for your reply!